# Row_number() that depends on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one column with zeros and ones with preserved order, where zeros indicate breaks between pieces of data.
Here is the example

```
A Ord
1 1 
1 2 
0 3 
0 4 
0 5 
1 6 
1 7 
1 8 
0 9 
1 10
```

What I would like to obtain is the same column where all elements after zero (or zeros) increase by 1 in comparison to previous pack of non-zero elements. Thus above example after transformartion has to look like this:

```
A Ord
1 1
1 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
2 6
2 7
2 8
0 9
3 10
```

The number of zeros and ones in each group can be any.
I tried to do it using different combinations of row_number() and join, but eventually failed.

Comment: What do you mean by "preserved order". Do you have another column that defines the order of the rows? What version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: maybe compine lag/lead with cummltive sum

Comment: Mikael, yes, I edited example so it should be more clear now. I use 2008 version

Comment: tables in relational database is unordered. you can force order based on a column.

Comment: do you have a primary key for table?

Comment: Homayoun Afshari, yes, column Ord

Comment: haki, I will check the internet. Haven't used these functions for a while

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2012 you can use `lag()` and `sum() over()`.

```
select iif(T.A = 0, 0, sum(T.C) over(order by T.Ord rows unbounded preceding)) as A,
       T.Ord
from (
     select Y.A,
            Y.Ord,
            iif(Y.A = 1 and isnull(lag(Y.A) over(order by Y.Ord), 0) = 0, 1, 0) as C
     from YourTable as Y
     ) as T
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f4a61/1)

Comment: It works perfect. Thank you! I will look closer into your answer and try to adept it for 2008